# Executing insert query in linux terminals

Tags: mysql, linux

I have a big file, that has 5000 queries.I want to execute those insert query in terminals. I have read some documents and used

```
    mysql -u root -p
```

comment to connect to mysql but i got the following details:

```
   The program 'mysql' can be found in the following packages:
    * mysql-client-core-5.5
    * mariadb-client-core-5.5
    * mysql-client-core-5.6
    * percona-xtradb-cluster-client-5.5
      Ask your administrator to install one of them
```

I dont know what should i do to execute those queries..
can anyone help me??
thanks in advance..

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear, what are you having trouble with?

Comment: Make sure you've installed MySQL and that a MySQL executable is in your path, or that you provide the full path to the executable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

First create a 'insert.sql' whitch is content your queries. (simple text file, like this example)

```
USE yourdb;
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES
    ( 1, 0, 0, "aaaaa" ),
    ( 2, 0, 0, "bbbbb" ),
    ( 3, 0, 0, "ccccc" );
```

Then you can execute the queries from terminal this way:

```
mysql --user=root --password=XXXX < insert.sql
```